# Splitting polydat into all connected components in VTK

Tags: c++, vtk

I have an obj file mesh and I want to extract all connected element in vtk. I already tried vtkConnectivityFilter as well as vtkPolyDataConnectivityFilter.

````
 auto connectivityFilter =  vtkSmartPointer<vtkConnectivityFilter>::New();
      connectivityFilter->SetInputData(inPoly);
      connectivityFilter->SetExtractionModeToSpecifiedRegions();
      connectivityFilter->ColorRegionsOn();
      connectivityFilter->Update();
  for (int i = 1; i < connectivityFilter->GetNumberOfExtractedRegions(); i++)
    {
       connectivityFilter->AddSpecifiedRegion(i);
       connectivityFilter->Update();
       auto poly = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();
       poly->ShallowCopy(connectivityFilter->GetOutput());
    }
}```
````

Comment: Can you explain what goes wrong ?

Comment: Hi @NicoVuaille , thank you for response, actually it will extract only isolated mesh but not extract any connected parts of triangle mesh !

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is:

- compute the connectivity with `vtkPolydataConnectivityFilter` in AllRegion mode. It creates an array with a unique value per connected points.
- in the loop over NumberOfExtractedRegions, extract polydata with a `vtkThreshold`, setup as `ThresholdBetween(i,i)`

https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkThreshold.html#a20f1127a1da274eea9791c15410e9935

https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPolyDataConnectivityFilter.html#details